# Get rid of _id field in mongoDB with codeigniter

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

I want to know how we can get db data without the _id field in mongoDB on codeigniter

```
db.products.find( { qty: { $gt: 25 } }, { _id: 0, qty: 0 } )
```

- I need to convert the above code into codeigniter understandable format.

If anyone can help please..? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like [JSON](http://www.json.org/) data, you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in php to convert it to a php variable, either an object or an array, then you can get rid of the field using [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).